# Installing tabu.sty with MacTeX 2010.

Tags: packages, installing, mactex

I use MacTeX 2010, and I need to install tabu.sty.
I run tlmgr to install the package, but without luck.

```
> sudo tlmgr install tabu.sty

tlmgr: package repository http://ctan.math.utah.edu/ctan/tex-archive/systems/texlive/tlnet
package tabu.sty not present in package repository.
```

- What would be the easiest way to install tabu.sty?
- Why tabu.sty is not in repository?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The name of the package for the purposes of `tlmgr` is not `tabu.sty` it's `tabu` because packages often contain a bunch of other files (documentation for sure, plus other files that you may not be aware of.)  So the way to install `tabu` is:

```
sudo tlmgr install tabu
```

Comment: Don't forget that TeX Live Utility comes with MacTeX (in /Applications/TeX); it's a very friendly front-end to tlmgr.