# How to color the font of a single row in a table?

Tags: tables, color

I have a table and I want to make the font color red for just one row (not the background). How do I do that?
Here's my table:

```
  \begin{tabular}{ l | l l l l }
        & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 
    \hline 
    1   & A & B & C & D \\ 
    2   & A & B & C & D \\ 
    3   & A & B & C & D \\ 
    4   & A & B & C & D \\ 
  \end{tabular}
```

Comment: A more general answer (multiple rows at once) is helpful here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/97015/95423

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You could use the `tabu` environment of the [`tabu`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tabu) package with the command `\rowfont`, for example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tabu}{ l | l l l l }
  \rowfont{\color{red}}
        & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 
    \hline 
    1   & A & B & C & D \\ 
    2   & A & B & C & D \\ 
    3   & A & B & C & D \\ 
    4   & A & B & C & D \\ 
  \end{tabu}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Much better than my idea of a per-column `\color{red}`.

Comment: Is an unaltered `tabu` environment equivalent to an unaltered `tabular` environment?

Comment: @doncherry: unaltered it behaves very similarly. Differences are explained in the manual, there's a section dedicated to it.

Comment: That's annoying, my texlive package doesn't come with tabu.sty. I've even installed texlive-full. I'm using xubuntu 10.04 by the way. I can't figure out how to install tabu.sty manually could someone point me in the right direction? Thanks

Comment: @Eddy: don't worry, installation is not hard, and by trying that you will get further knowledge. You can download it from [CTAN](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/tabu), and see [How do I install a dtx file](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6925/how-do-i-install-a-dtx-fil), [Placing sty files](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1137/where-do-i-place-my-own-sty-files-to-make-them-available-to-all-my-tex-files) and if you use TeX Live (not Xubuntu repositories) [Installing tabu.sty](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15099/installing-tabu-sty-with-mactex-2010).

Comment: Figured out how to do it: 1. Download tabu.dtx and tabu.ins 2. run `latex tabu.ins` 3. move tabu.sty to $HOME/texmf/tex/latex/commonfiles 4. run `texhash $HOME/texmf`

Comment: @StefanKottwitz thanks for sharing that solution. I tried it on a table in a blank tex file and it works wonderfully. However, when trying to implement it in the same table part of a much longer document, this causes a timeout in compilation (I am using overleaf). Are you aware of any possible clashes with other packages?

Comment: Unfortunately, the tabu package appears to be broken and unmaintained these days.

Answer (score 37):

If you don't want to use the `tabu` package you can define a `\rowstyle` command together with supporting column types `+` and `=` as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\makeatletter

\newcommand*{\@rowstyle}{}

\newcommand*{\rowstyle}[1]{% sets the style of the next row
  \gdef\@rowstyle{#1}%
  \@rowstyle\ignorespaces%
}

\newcolumntype{=}{% resets the row style
  >{\gdef\@rowstyle{}}%
}

\newcolumntype{+}{% adds the current row style to the next column
  >{\@rowstyle}%
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ =l | +l +l +l +l }
  \rowstyle{\color{red}}
      & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
  \hline
  1   & A & B & C & D \\
  2   & A & B & C & D \\
  3   & A & B & C & D \\
  4   & A & B & C & D \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Excellent answer. I hate the ```tabu``` package and its documentation. Your solution works with ```tabular*``` too!

Answer (score 3):

In `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`, you have a command `\RowStyle` to specify  formatting instructions for the current row.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{l|llll}
\RowStyle{\color{red}}
    & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 
\hline 
1   & A & B & C & D \\ 
2   & A & B & C & D \\ 
3   & A & B & C & D \\ 
4   & A & B & C & D \\ 
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the first code]

There is also a key `color` for that command `\RowStyle`. `color=red` will insert `\leavevmode\color{red}` with the `\leavevmode` which is necessary in columns of type `p`, `m`, `b` and `X` (otherwise, there is an extra vertical space).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{l|p{1cm}p{1cm}p{1cm}p{1cm}}
\RowStyle[color=red]{}
    & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 
\hline 
1   & A & B & C & D \\ 
2   & A & B & C & D \\ 
3   & A & B & C & D \\ 
4   & A & B & C & D \\ 
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the second code]