# Different font sizes for different rows in table

Tags: tables, fontsize

I want to put different sizes of fonts (smaller) into different rows of my LaTeX table. I found that it is possible to have different font sizes for different columns of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2270082/latex-how-do-i-change-the-font-size-of-a-table-column). Is there any simple way to put different fonts to LaTeX table rows ?

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/26364/94816

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use the package tabu which provides the command `\rowfont`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabu}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabu}{ll}
\rowfont{\scriptsize}
Hello & World \\
Foo & Bar \\
\rowfont{\huge}
Hello & World
\end{tabu}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Too bad `tabu` is no longer maintained. Not recommended to use anymore. https://github.com/tabu-issues-for-future-maintainer/tabu

Answer (score 8):

Creating your own `\rowfont{<font>}` *switch* is also possible.

Using the [`array` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/array), you can insert elements in front of every column via the definition of a new column type. This insertion helps span the group associated with each `tabular` cell.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}% http://ctan.org/pkg/array
\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro{\endtabular}{\rowfont{}}% Clear row font
\makeatother
\newcommand{\rowfonttype}{}% Current row font
\newcommand{\rowfont}[1]{% Set current row font
   \gdef\rowfonttype{#1}#1%
}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\rowfonttype}l}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{LL}
  \rowfont{\scriptsize}%
  Hello & World \\
  \rowfont{\normalsize}%
  Foo & Bar \\
  \rowfont{\huge}%
  Hello & World
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

`\rowfont{<font>}` globally (re)defines `\rowfonttype`, and also inserts it into the current cell. Resetting the font is required in a subsequent row (via `\rowfont{\normalsize}` or otherwise).

End-of-`tabular` resetting is automated by appending `\rowfont{}` to `\endtabular`.

Comment: Can this be done without redefining the column as well?

Comment: @Alenanno: One may have to tap into the definition of `\tabular` where ``\\`` is defined and add `\rowfont{}` similar to what was done for `\endtabular`.

Comment: Oh, sounds complicated. :)

Comment: If you use `\makecell` (from makecell package) in one cell, the font size stops being applied from that cell on unless also including `\rowfont` in that cell.

Answer (score 8):

I tested all other methods above with packages but I found this simple method by [David](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/27256191#27256191) most useful -- actually I got all kind of malfunctioning with other answers such as only one element in a row changed the size of the text and so on, this may be due to rotating's sidewaystable but anyway -- this most simplest method works!

> \footnotesize \begin{tabular} then \normalsize\bfseries hello for the title

and other fontsizes contain `\tiny, \scriptsize, \footnotesize, \small, \normalsize, \large, \Large, \LARGE, \huge` and `\Huge`. More in [here](https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Font_sizes,_families,_and_styles).

Comment: (+1) would you please provide a mwe in your answer. many thanks.