# Format table number alignment

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, fontsize, siunitx

I am having a few problems with the following code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{
 l
  S[table-format = 4.2]
  S[table-format = 4.2] 
  S[table-format = 4.2]
  S[table-format = 4.2]
  S[table-format = 4.2]
  S[table-format = 4.2]
  S[table-format = 4.2]
  S[table-format = 4.2]
  S[table-format = 4.2]
}
\toprule
 &  \multicolumn{3}{c}{HF} &    \multicolumn{3}{c}{LF} &        \multicolumn{3}{c}{HF-LF} \\
 \midrule
Excess &    -0.79\textsuperscript{***} &                               &                               &    -0.90\textsuperscript{***} &                               &                               &                         -0.11 &                               &                               \\
 &                \tiny(0.152) &                               &                               &                  \tiny(0.161) &                               &                               &                  \tiny(0.066) &                               &                               \\
$\alpha$ &                             &    -0.77\textsuperscript{***} &    -0.79\textsuperscript{***} &                               &    -0.89\textsuperscript{***} &    -0.94\textsuperscript{***} &                               &      -0.13\textsuperscript{*} &     -0.16\textsuperscript{**} \\
 &                             &                  \tiny(0.161) &                  \tiny(0.172) &                               &                  \tiny(0.174) &                  \tiny(0.178) &                               &                  \tiny(0.066) &                  \tiny(0.069) \\
MKT &                              &                         -0.07 &                         -0.06 &                               &                         -0.02 &                         -0.00 &                               &       0.05\textsuperscript{*} &      0.06\textsuperscript{**} \\
 &                             &                  \tiny(0.056) &                  \tiny(0.064) &                               &                  \tiny(0.038) &                  \tiny(0.049) &                               &                  \tiny(0.028) &                  \tiny(0.027) \\
SMB &                              &                               &                          0.04 &                               &                               &                          0.04 &                               &                               &                          0.00 \\
 &                             &                               &                  \tiny(0.095) &                               &                               &                  \tiny(0.084) &                               &                               &                  \tiny(0.024) \\
HML &                              &                               &                          0.04 &                               &                               &                          0.11 &                               &                               &                          0.06 \\
 &                             &                               &                  \tiny(0.085) &                               &                               &                  \tiny(0.072) &                               &                               &                  \tiny(0.041) \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

I would be grateful for any suggestions where to look in the docs and/or solutions and improvements.

The issues I cannot figure out how to fix:

- The number in parenthesis are standard errors and should be right aligned with the bigger numbers above them. Basically, the `)` should end before any asterisk. Any approximate result that improves is also ok.
- The asterisks at the right end of the table are truncated (why?)
- [minor] Can I improve the code and avoid typing `\tiny` for each entry in each second row?
- [minor] Can I improve the code and avoid typing `\textsuperscript{<asterisks>}` by definying a special column format? I will only have this format at -#.##*** with variable length of the whole part.

Answer (score 1):

I went with the following implementation which partly satisfies needs, although does not provide a generic solution to the problem:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{booktabs,tabu}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabu}{l  
      *{9}{S[table-format          = -2.2,
             table-space-text-post = $^{***}$ ,
             table-align-text-post = false,
             table-text-alignment  = center]
             @{}
             }
      }
    \toprule
                            &\multicolumn{3}{c}{Low Frequency} &\multicolumn{3}{c}{High Frequency} &\multicolumn{3}{c}{HF-LF} \\
    \cmidrule(lr){2-4}\cmidrule(lr){5-7}\cmidrule(lr){8-10}
                     Excess &-0.79$^{***}$ &              &              &-0.90$^{***}$ &              &              &        -0.11 &              &              \\
    \rowfont{\footnotesize} &    {(0.152)} &              &              &    {(0.161)} &              &              &    {(0.066)} &              &              \\[3pt]
                   $\alpha$ &              &-0.77$^{***}$ &-0.79$^{***}$ &              &-0.89$^{***}$ &-0.94$^{***}$ &              &    -0.13$^*$ & -0.16$^{**}$ \\
    \rowfont{\footnotesize} &              &    {(0.161)} &    {(0.172)} &              &    {(0.174)} &    {(0.178)} &              &    {(0.066)} &    {(0.069)} \\[3pt]
                        MKT &              &        -0.07 &        -0.06 &              &        -0.02 &        -0.00 &              &     0.05$^*$ &  0.06$^{**}$ \\
    \rowfont{\footnotesize} &              &    {(0.056)} &    {(0.064)} &              &    {(0.038)} &    {(0.049)} &              &    {(0.028)} &    {(0.027)} \\[3pt]
                        SMB &              &              &         0.04 &              &              &         0.04 &              &              &         0.00 \\
    \rowfont{\footnotesize} &              &              &    {(0.095)} &              &              &    {(0.084)} &              &              &    {(0.024)} \\[3pt]
                        HML &              &              &         0.04 &              &              &         0.11 &              &              &         0.06 \\
    \rowfont{\footnotesize} &              &              &    {(0.085)} &              &              &    {(0.072)} &              &              &    {(0.041)} \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabu}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The main issue is that I cannot enforce a size on decimal entries that are in mathmode. To set the font size for the whole row I used the tabu solution explained on [Different font sizes for different rows in table](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34225/different-font-sizes-for-different-rows). However, I need the standard errors to be in text mode `{(###)}`, or the size command is not propagated (numeric entries are parsed by either `siunitx` or `dcolumn` and split in components, hence only the first component of the number is affected by the font command). The drawback in this solution is that alignment of the `{text}` part is somewhat hacky and fine-tuned for this specific application.