# Different font sizes and row heights in tables

Tags: tables, fontsize

I have to typeset a table with different font sizes in different table rows. I am using the approach suggested by Werner in [Different font sizes for different rows in table](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34225/different-font-sizes-for-different-rows-in-table/34226):

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}
\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro{\endtabular}{\rowfont{}}% Clear row font
\makeatother
\newcommand{\rowfonttype}{}% Current row font
\newcommand{\rowfont}[1]{% Set current row font
   \gdef\rowfonttype{#1}#1%
}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\rowfonttype}l}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}[t]{ll}
    \toprule
    Hello & World \\
    Hello & World \\
    Hello & World \\    
    Hello & World \\
    Hello & World \\
    Hello & World \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\begin{tiny}
\begin{tabular}[t]{ll}
    \toprule
    Hello & World \\
    Hello & World \\
    Hello & World \\    
    Hello & World \\
    Hello & World \\
    Hello & World \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{tiny}

\begin{tabular}[t]{LL}
    \toprule
    \rowfont{\tiny}%
    Hello & World \\
    Hello & World \\
    Hello & World \\    
    \rowfont{\normalsize}%
    Hello & World \\
    Hello & World \\
    Hello & World \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

This gives me the following result:

[image]

Apparently, `\newfont` works nicely to adjust the font size in the third table, but the height of the table rows is still calculated based on `normalsize`. Is there a way to adjust the height of the first three rows of the third table to the "normal" height for `tiny`?

---

**Follow-up**

David's solution works fine with the MWE I provided. However, using longtable, I get the following:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{threeparttablex}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}

\setstretch{1.25}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.00}

% Use different font sizes in table
\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro{\endtabular}{\rowfont{}}% Clear row font
\makeatother
\newcommand{\rowfonttype}{}% Current row font
\newcommand{\rowfont}[1]{% Set current row font
   \gdef\rowfonttype{#1}#1%
}
\newcolumntype{P}{>{\rowfonttype}p}

\begin{document}

\begin{ThreePartTable}
\setstretch{1.00}
\begin{TableNotes}[para,flushleft]
Some caption.
\end{TableNotes}
\begin{footnotesize}

\begin{longtable}{@{}P{1cm}P{1cm}P{1cm}P{1cm}@{}}
\caption{A list}\\

\toprule
\endfirsthead
\captionsetup{labelsep=endash}
\caption[]{\emph{continued from previous page}}\\
\toprule
\endhead
\midrule
\multicolumn{4}{@{}r@{}}{\emph{Continued on next page}} \\
\endfoot
\bottomrule
\insertTableNotes
\endlastfoot
    xxx & xxx & xxx & xxx \\
    xxx & xxx & xxx & xxx \\
    xxx & xxx & xxx & xxx \\
    \rowfont{\tiny}%
    xxx & xxx & xxx & xxx \\
    xxx & xxx & xxx & xxx \\
    xxx & xxx & xxx & xxx \ \rowfont{\normalsize}%
\end{longtable}

\end{footnotesize}
\end{ThreePartTable}


\renewcommand\arraystretch{0} 
\begin{ThreePartTable}
\setstretch{1.00}
\begin{TableNotes}[para,flushleft]
Some caption.
\end{TableNotes}
\begin{footnotesize}

\begin{longtable}{@{}P{1cm}P{1cm}P{1cm}P{1cm}@{}}
\caption{A list}\\

\toprule
\endfirsthead
\captionsetup{labelsep=endash}
\caption[]{\emph{continued from previous page}}\\
\toprule
\endhead
\midrule
\multicolumn{4}{@{}r@{}}{\emph{Continued on next page}} \\
\endfoot
\bottomrule
\insertTableNotes
\endlastfoot
    xxx & xxx & xxx & xxx \\
    xxx & xxx & xxx & xxx \\
    xxx & xxx & xxx & xxx \\
    \rowfont{\tiny}%
    xxx & xxx & xxx & xxx \\
    xxx & xxx & xxx & xxx \\
    xxx & xxx & xxx & xxx \ \rowfont{\normalsize}%
\end{longtable}

\end{footnotesize}
\end{ThreePartTable}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Is there a way to also have the appropriate row height for the `tiny` rows here?

Comment: you forgot to add the `\strut` back. compare your `P` to the `L` in the posted answer, nor did you use `\noalign`,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}
\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro{\endtabular}{\gdef\rowfonttype{}}% Clear row font
\makeatother
\newcommand{\rowfonttype}{}% Current row font
\newcommand{\rowfont}[1]{% Set current row font
   \noalign{\gdef\rowfonttype{#1}}}%
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\rowfonttype\strut}l}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}[t]{ll}
    \toprule
    Hello & World \\
    Hello & World \\
    Hello & World \\    
    Hello & World \\
    Hello & World \\
    Hello & World \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\begin{tiny}
\begin{tabular}[t]{ll}
    \toprule
    Hello & World \\
    Hello & World \\
    Hello & World \\    
    Hello & World \\
    Hello & World \\
    Hello & World \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{tiny}

\renewcommand\arraystretch{0}
\begin{tabular}[t]{LL}
    \toprule
    \rowfont{\tiny}%
    Hello & World \\
    Hello & World \\
    Hello & World \\    
    \rowfont{\normalsize}%
    Hello & World \\
    Hello & World \\
    Hello & World \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```