# Text size in single table row

Tags: tables, fontsize, siunitx

i want to include two letters in the S column of the siunitx package. As there are no measured values for the particular row, I want to label them with "ND". Can I include this, or does anyone have another idea to mark these rows?

The second question, in combination with the above mentioned, is: How can I change the font size in a specific row? 
Until now, I want to add a row with a smaller font under the table including the text "ND - not determined".

Thank you in advance for your help.

PS. The table is a normal *tabular* environment.

```
\begin{table}[ht!]
\caption[XX]{XX}\label{tab:XX} 
\centering
\begin{tabular}{llSS}
\toprule
&\textbf{XX}    & \textbf{XX} &\textbf{XX}\\
                &                   & [x\SI{E13}{milli\liter}]               & [\SI{}{\percent}]\\
    \midrule
        1       & XX                & ND         & ND         \\
        2       & XX                & 0.14       & 48.25      \\        
        8       & XX                & 20.8       & 26.59       \\ \midrule
 \multicolumn{4}{l}{ND = not determined} \\ 
     \bottomrule\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! See the answer to this [similar question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/359494/different-font-sizes-and-row-heights-in-tables).

Comment: Please provide an example of small document with your table that we not need to writze such document from scratch.BTW, for insert "ND" in ˛`S` column just enclose it in curly braces: `{ND}`. For note to table you can use `tablenotes` drom the `threeparttable` package or simple `\multicolumn{...}{l}{\\footnotesize ND: ....}`

Comment: Thanks, I added the table into my original question. Ah, the ND has to be put into curly braces. Sometimes it is to easy :D