# Change font color of multiple rows in a table

Tags: tables, color

I found the following post to change the font color of a single row in a table:

[How to color the font of a single row in a table?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26360/how-to-color-the-font-of-a-single-row-in-a-table)

My row is a long table with 70 rows and for about 25 the I want to change the font color. I was wondering if there is a better way of coloring these 25 rows rather than using `\rowfont{\color{red}}` 25 times?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{color,array}

\makeatletter


\def\zapcolorreset{\let\reset@color\relax\ignorespaces}
\def\colorrows#1{\noalign{\aftergroup\zapcolorreset#1}\ignorespaces}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ll}
1&2\\
1&2\\
1&2\\\colorrows{\color{red}}
1&2\\
1&2\\
1&2\\\colorrows{\color{black}}
1&2\\
1&2\\
1&2
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Doesn't this need something like `\edef\endtabular{\unexpanded\expandafter{\endtabular}\noexpand\reset@color}` as well to ensure that the colour stops at the end of the table (if not manually reset)?