# How to change font type faces in table row?

Tags: tables, fonts, macros

Is possible to change font faces in whole row on similar way as it is possible for columns?

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{array}

    \begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{>{\bfseries}c *{4}{c}}
    \hline
 A & B & C & D\\% text in this row should bold or italic ...
    \hline
 1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\
 5 & 6 & 7 & 8\\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
    \end{document}
```

For example, is possible to define macro similar to macro `\rowcolor`` defined in [David Carlisle answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/97013/change-font-color-of-multiple-rows-in-a-table), which will change font face in just one table row?