# Tabu table text-colored header: vertical and horizontal alignment, one line and word wrap cases

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, color, vertical-alignment, tabu

We have a latex `tabu` table with custom header's style: it has different alignment, color and shape from other table rows.

BTW `XeLaTeX` is used.

Header could be short on length, see the pictures and minimal working example (MWE, in the end).

It is neccesarry to apply following style to header text:

- bold;
- aligned to horizontal center;
- aligned to vertical center (both for one line or word wrapped cases);
- custom color is `#0070C0`;

**Desired result**

[image: Desired]

We have applied `\rowfont{}` command to the first `tabu` table row as in answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/26363/123948

```
\taburulecolor{DarkBlue}
\tabulinesep = 1mm
\begin{tabu} to 170 mm {
    |X[2]       %  |X[2,m]
    |X[1.5]     %  |X[1.5,m]
    |X[0.6, C]  %  |X[0.6, C,m]
    |X[2]       %  |X[2,m]
    |X[0.6, C]| %  |X[0.6, C,m]|
    }
\rowfont{\centering\bfseries\color{Blue}}
%...
```

and:

- text became bold using `\bfseries`;
- aligned to horizontal center using `\centering`;
- color is `\definecolor{Blue}{HTML}{1C8CCC}`;
- tried `tabu`'s `m` colunm type to align to vertical center, but it works only in wrapped case (one-line is not) and it **affects to whole table**, but we need header only.

**Actual result**
without `m` type because it affects to the whole table

[image: actual]

**Questions**

- How to align vertically only header text using `\rowfont{}` (or other way)?
- Are horizontal alignment and coloring of header row implemented correctly or there are better ways?

**Minimal working example**

XeLaTeX is used.

```
\documentclass[10pt, oneside, a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=1.5cm,
    top=2cm,bottom=2cm,bindingoffset=0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{indentfirst} 
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\definecolor{DarkBlue}{HTML}{0070C0} 
\definecolor{Blue}{HTML}{1C8CCC} 
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Arial}


%--------------------------------------------
\begin{document}

\taburulecolor{DarkBlue}
\tabulinesep = 1mm
\begin{tabu} to 170 mm {
    |X[2]       %  |X[2,m]
    |X[1.5]     %  |X[1.5,m]
    |X[0.6, C]  %  |X[0.6, C,m]
    |X[2]       %  |X[2,m]
    |X[0.6, C]| %  |X[0.6, C,m]|
    }
\rowfont{\centering\bfseries\color{Blue}}

\hline

Status
    & Visual indication: color and indication type %% WORD WRAP
%        & Visual indication %% one line
    & Symbol
    & Audible signal
    & Priority\\ \hline

Alarm active, not acknowledge 
    & Red, blinking 
    & picture
    & Accompanied by an audible signal, as 3 short audible signals repeated every 7 s
    & High 
    \\ \hline

Alarm active, silenced 
    & Red, blinking 
    & picture
    & Silent 
    & 
    \\ \hline
\end{tabu}
\end{document}
```

Comment: welcome to tex.se! `tabu` is nice package, unfortunately it is buggy and no more maintained.

Comment: Thank you, @Zarko. If `tabu` is not actual now, which if existing table packaged is powerful enough to substitute tabu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:**

- `tabu` is nice package, reach of features but unfortunately it is buggy and no more maintained.
- problem is in use `color{...}` (independent of used `latex` engine)
- as workaround see if the following solution is acceptable for you

  - remove `\rowcolor{...}`
  - define new commanad (see *mwe* below, let its name be `\ch` (*column header*) which carry about *boldface font*, *color* of fonts and *vertical spacing* of cells content

```
\documentclass[10pt, oneside, a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=1.5cm,
    top=2cm,bottom=2cm,bindingoffset=0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\definecolor{DarkBlue}{HTML}{0070C0}
\definecolor{Blue}{HTML}{1C8CCC}
\usepackage{multirow}
%\usepackage{polyglossia} % i haven't this fonts
%\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Arial}% i haven't this fonts

\newcommand\ch[1]{\centering                        % <--- added
    \begin{tabular}{@{}>{\color{Blue}\bfseries}c@{}}
                    #1
    \end{tabular}
                  }

\begin{document}
\taburulecolor{DarkBlue}
\tabulinesep=1mm       
\begin{tabu} to 170 mm {
    |X[2]       %  |X[2,m]
    |X[1.5]     %  |X[1.5,m]
    |X[0.6, C]  %  |X[0.6, C,m]
    |X[2]       %  |X[2,m]
    |X[0.6, C]| %  |X[0.6, C,m]|
    }
\hline
\ch{Status}
    & \ch{Visual indication:\\ color and\\ indication type}
    & \ch{Symbol}
    & \ch{Audible signal}
    & \ch{Priority}\\ \hline   

Alarm active, not acknowledge
    & Red, blinking
    & picture
    & Accompanied by an audible signal, as 3 short audible signals repeated every 7 s
    & High
    \\ \hline    
Alarm active, silenced
    & Red, blinking
    & picture
    & Silent
    &
    \\ \hline
\end{tabu}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for answer. I'm agree that `\color` should be replaced as you wrote. It is not a problem to color each head cell text using your solution. But this solution doesn't make the head text vertically center aligned as I see.

Comment: BTW. If tabu is obsolete and is not consistent maybe you know
any other package to substitute tabu? We need following features:
- X-type columns (auto width for specified size) with ability to adjust horizontal and vertical  alignment for whole column, and in the same time text wrap, padding control, text and figures positioning (tabularx for example has X width columns but it don't know how to satisfy other mentioned style)

Comment: see edit of answer, hopefully now is as you like to have

Comment: as you mentioned: `tabularx`, but missing features you have to add with some other package. for examples: for figures is handy `[export]{adjustbox}`, for vertical align only in some rows on the way as i do in above answer, etc.

Comment: yes, the figure of your result now shows exactly what I need. But I cannot find `\ch{}` command definition in your MWE. I suppose it is something like `\newcommand{\ch}[1]{\textcolor{\textbf{#1}}}`, but how does vertical alignment is inplement?

Comment: ups, by mistace i erase command `\ch` ... it is quite "sophisticated". ... i will de-erase it :) (soon)

Comment: thank you! I could test the solution only on Monday, so that is not urgent)

Comment: thanks. But I have problems with horizontal alighnment copiling your solution: only second column depends on `c` in `{@{}>{\color{Blue}\bfseries}c@{}}`, other header columns are aligned to the left. (I don't know how to attach a figure to a comment).

Comment: as you see from provided image of provided code compilation, i haven't this problem. i will examine my code again asap.

Comment: may this behaviour depend on packages and/or MiKTeX version?

Comment: it is always good to have recent version of packages, normally they have less bugs (and some times new ones:-( ). i tested my *mwe* with not recent miktex and work as expected. columns except headers are aligned as determines columns types, column headers are horizontally and vertically centered (in blue color) .

Comment: I've installed the latest MiKTeX version and now MWE works as expected. Thank you so much.

Comment: Sorry, but I mistaken: still I have problems with horizontal alighnment copiling your solution: only second column depends on `c`. Even if I try to align to the right: `{@{}>\color{Blue}\bfseries}r@{}}`.

Comment: i test my solution again (with code copied from my answer) ... and it works as expected. result is as shown in answer. i haven't any idea how you succeed my *mwe* to not work as expected. you should have something what is hidden to me. i can only suggest you to ask new question, where you show your test *mwe* and obtained result and clear indication what is not as you expected. maybe someone else will see, what is the problem.

Comment: @AndreiLosenkov, sorry for all inconveniences caused by my superficiality in observing of problem, testing of my answer and copying of correct code version of  developed solution.