# Сode from answer does not work: Tabu table text-colored header

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment, tabu, miktex2.9

> i test my solution again (with code copied from my answer) ... and it
>   works as expected. result is as shown in answer. i haven't any idea
>   how you succeed my mwe to not work as expected. you should have
>   something what is hidden to me. i can only suggest you to ask new
>   question, where you show your test mwe and obtained result and clear
>   indication what is not as you expected. maybe someone else will see,
>   what is the problem.

**Description of problem:** 
We have a latex `tabu` table with custom header's style: it has different alignment, color and shape from other table rows.

BTW `XeLaTeX` is used.

It is neccesarry to apply following style to header text:

- bold;
- aligned to horizontal center;
- aligned to vertical center (both for one line or word wrapped cases);
- custom color is `#0070C0`;

Old version of MiKTeX deleted. We have installed the latest version of MiKTeX (2.9). We fixed a bug with package fontspec (now version 2.6d).

**Desired result:** [image]

**Actual result:** [image]

We tested this code on computers of our colleagues. And result is same.

Why is alignment not working , and another person all running?
What could be reason? 
Сan anyone else verify this code?

Is there any other way to solve original problem? It's important for us.

I copied this code from response [Tabu table text-colored header: vertical and horizontal alignment, one line and word wrap cases](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/387032/tabu-table-text-colored-header-vertical-and-horizontal-alignment-one-line-and)

```
\documentclass[10pt, oneside, a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=1.5cm,
    top=2cm,bottom=2cm,bindingoffset=0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\definecolor{DarkBlue}{HTML}{0070C0}
\definecolor{Blue}{HTML}{1C8CCC}
\usepackage{multirow}
%\usepackage{polyglossia} % i haven't this fonts
%\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Arial}% i haven't this fonts

\newcommand\ch[1]{\begin{tabular}{@{}>{\color{Blue}\bfseries}c@{}}% <-- added
                    #1
                  \end{tabular}
                  }

\begin{document}
\taburulecolor{DarkBlue}
\tabulinesep=1mm       
\begin{tabu} to 170 mm {
    |X[2]       %  |X[2,m]
    |X[1.5]     %  |X[1.5,m]
    |X[0.6, C]  %  |X[0.6, C,m]
    |X[2]       %  |X[2,m]
    |X[0.6, C]| %  |X[0.6, C,m]|
    }
\hline
\ch{Status}
    & \ch{Visual indication:\\ color and\\ indication type}
    & \ch{Symbol}
    & \ch{Audible signal}
    & \ch{Priority}\\ \hline   

Alarm active, not acknowledge
    & Red, blinking
    & picture
    & Accompanied by an audible signal, as 3 short audible signals repeated every 7 s
    & High
    \\ \hline    
Alarm active, silenced
    & Red, blinking
    & picture
    & Silent
    &
    \\ \hline
\end{tabu}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! You are right. The image is of an other version of the answer (see version 1). @Zarko could you fix it please? (and answer with version one)  [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/387051/124842).

Comment: @Bobyandbob, i fixed my spurious code now. see my answer below and correction in the mine original answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you put each heading inside a `\multicolumn{1}{c}{...}` via the following macros:

```
\newcommand{\chbody}[1]{\begin{tabular}{@{}>{\color{Blue}\bfseries}c@{}}#1\end{tabular}}
\newcommand{\ch}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\chbody{#1}}}
\newcommand{\fch}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\chbody{#1}}}
```

(the `\fch` is just for the first column that also needs a vertical rule on the left).

This gives centered headings

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[10pt, oneside, a4paper]{report}

\usepackage[left=2cm,right=1.5cm,
    top=2cm,bottom=2cm,bindingoffset=0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\definecolor{DarkBlue}{HTML}{0070C0}
\definecolor{Blue}{HTML}{1C8CCC}

\newcommand{\chbody}[1]{\begin{tabular}{@{}>{\color{Blue}\bfseries}c@{}}#1\end{tabular}}
\newcommand{\ch}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\chbody{#1}}}
\newcommand{\fch}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\chbody{#1}}}

\begin{document}

\taburulecolor{DarkBlue}%
\tabulinesep=1mm
\begin{tabu} to 170 mm {
    |X[2]       %  |X[2,m]
    |X[1.5]     %  |X[1.5,m]
    |X[0.6, C]  %  |X[0.6, C,m]
    |X[2]       %  |X[2,m]
    |X[0.6, C]| %  |X[0.6, C,m]|
    }
\hline
\fch{Status}
    & \ch{Visual indication:\\ color and\\ indication type}
    & \ch{Symbol}
    & \ch{Audible signal}
    & \ch{Priority}\\ \hline
\tabuphantomline
Alarm active, not acknowledge
    & Red, blinking
    & picture
    & Accompanied by an audible signal, as 3 short audible signals repeated every 7 s
    & High
    \\ \hline
Alarm active, silenced
    & Red, blinking
    & picture
    & Silent
    &
    \\ \hline
\end{tabu}
\end{document}
```

Note I have added `\tabuphantomline` as recommended by the package's documentation and 
I have removed other unused packages from the preamble.

Answer (score 1):

also works with adding the missed part (what embarrassing) of my definition of `\ch` command:

```
    \newcommand\ch[1]{\centering% <-- missed, sorry
            \begin{tabular}{@{}>{\color{Blue}\bfseries}c@{}}
                        #1
                      \end{tabular}
                      }
```

sorry, i overlooked this twice ... (in result and at copy of the wrong version of my "development" of the answer) :-). this correction i also add to original answer

now complete *mwe* is (also tested with xelatex):

```
\documentclass[10pt, oneside, a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=1.5cm,
    top=2cm,bottom=2cm,bindingoffset=0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\definecolor{DarkBlue}{HTML}{0070C0}
\definecolor{Blue}{HTML}{1C8CCC}
\usepackage{multirow}
%\usepackage{polyglossia} % i haven't this fonts
%\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Arial}% i haven't this fonts

\newcommand\ch[1]{\centering% <-- added
        \begin{tabular}{@{}>{\color{Blue}\bfseries}c@{}}
                    #1
                  \end{tabular}
                  }

\begin{document}
\taburulecolor{DarkBlue}
\tabulinesep=1mm
\begin{tabu} to 170 mm {
    |X[2]       %  |X[2,m]
    |X[1.5]     %  |X[1.5,m]
    |X[0.6, C]  %  |X[0.6, C,m]
    |X[2]       %  |X[2,m]
    |X[0.6, C]| %  |X[0.6, C,m]|
    }
\hline
\ch{Status (now centered)}
    & \ch{Visual indication:\\ color and\\ indication type}
    & \ch{Symbol}
    & \ch{Audible signal}
    & \ch{Priority}\\ \hline

Alarm active, not acknowledge
    & Red, blinking
    & picture
    & Accompanied by an audible signal, as 3 short audible signals repeated every 7 s
    & High
    \\ \hline
Alarm active, silenced
    & Red, blinking
    & picture
    & Silent
    &
    \\ \hline
\end{tabu}
\end{document}
```

[image]

note: using of different font (enabled by xelatex) may require to increase columns widths the narrower columns: `|X[0.6, C]`.