# Longtable - Changing Font Color of Header Row doesnt extend to all cells

Tags: tables, formatting, color, longtable

I am using longtable package as most of the tables that I use tend to go on for multiple pages. What I want is now that the header row should be filled with blue colour and white text. The remainder rows should be black text with background fill changing between dark gray and white. This is the code I have but the output as you can see is not desirable.

```
     \documentclass[portrait]{report}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,table]{xcolor}
\definecolor{light-gray}{HTML}{E5E4E2}
\definecolor{light-cyan}{HTML}{E0FFFF}
\definecolor{vblue_new}{rgb}{0.433, 0.601, 0.750}  

\begin{document}
\begingroup
\small
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{1pt}
\rowcolors{1}{light-cyan}{light-gray}
\begin{longtable}{|p{\dimexpr0.3\textwidth-2\tabcolsep}|p{\dimexpr0.5\textwidth-2\tabcolsep}|p{\dimexpr0.2\textwidth-2\tabcolsep}|}
\hline\rowcolor{vblue_new}
\textcolor{white}{Lorem&Ipsum &Number}
\endhead  \hline  \endfoot

Lorem&Ipsum&86\\
Lorem&Ipsum&86\\
Lorem&Ipsum&86\\
Lorem&Ipsum&86\\
Lorem&Ipsum&86\\
Lorem&Ipsum&86\\
Lorem&Ipsum&86\\
Lorem&Ipsum&86\\


\end{longtable}\endgroup

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of above code]

[image]

Comment: Use `\textcolor{white}{Lorem} & \textcolor{white}{Ipsum} & \textcolor{white}{Number}` instead of `\textcolor{white}{Lorem & Ipsum & Number}` which causes an error (`! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text>
}`). For an alternative see here: [How to color the font of a single row in a table?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/26360/134144)

Comment: The output of your document is `! Missing } inserted.` after a tex error it is usually best not even to look at the pdf, and if asking a question about the error, show the error message not the pdf.  TeX makes no attempt to make sensible output after an error it just recovers enough to try to syntax check the rest of the document