# Not able to compile when trying to change font color of specified tabular rows

Tags: tables

I am trying to change the text color of an entire row of a `tabular`, without using the `tabu` package. I want to employ [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/26364/15622).

What am I doing wrong such that the following MWE does not compile? I get the error message, "LaTeX Error: Command @ already defined."

```
\documentclass[oneside,11pt]{book}

\usepackage[semibold,tt=false]{libertine}
\usepackage{libertinust1math}
\usepackage[font={sf,small},labelsep=quad,labelfont=sc]{caption}
\usepackage[subrefformat=parens]{subcaption}
\usepackage[
  expansion = false ,
  tracking = smallcaps ,
  letterspace = 40 ,
]{microtype}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{acro}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{%
  detect-family, detect-shape,
  product-units = power,
  list-final-separator = {, and },
  retain-explicit-plus,
  input-comparators = {<=>\approx\ge\geq\gg\le\leq\ll\sim\lesssim\gtrsim}
}
\DeclareSIUnit[number-unit-product = ]\percent{\char`\%}

% Code from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/26364/15622
\newcommand*{\@rowstyle}{}
\newcommand*{\rowstyle}[1]{% sets the style of the next row
  \gdef\@rowstyle{#1}%
  \@rowstyle\ignorespaces%
}
\newcolumntype{=}{% resets the row style
  >{\gdef\@rowstyle{}}%
}
\newcolumntype{+}{% adds the current row style to the next column
  >{\@rowstyle}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{=l +l +l}
    \toprule
    A & {B} & {C}\\
    \midrule
    \rowstyle{\color{red}}
    Bob & \SI{75}{\percent} & -1.11\\
    Carla & \SI{75}{\percent} & 2.22\\
    Dale & \SI{75}{\percent} & -3.33\\
    Ena & \SI{75}{\percent} & 4.44\\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{A}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: \makeatletter
is missing i think from the code

Comment: What's wrong with `\rowcolor`?

Comment: @egreg Do you mean the one from the `colortbl` package?

Comment: @Andrew Of course.

Comment: @egreg Can I use `\rowcolor` to change the font color and not the shading color of the row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Too long for a comment. I hope that the following approach can be an alternative when one needs to color the selected rows of your table, the rests of the rows, or even more rows without repeating the color specification.

**Output**

[image]

It is important to mention that the solution can be used with pdfTeX only. Also, there are some other limitations, but in many cases the approach works fine.

**Usign the approach**

Simply define your favorite rgb color specification, e.g., by using `\def\mycolor{.6 0 .8}`. Further, use the command `\rowclr` at the beginning of the row (or, generally, somewhere in the row) to color the rest of the row. To apply the defined color, write `\rowclr\mycolor`. If you need to color more rows at once, it is better to use the commands `\startclr\mycolor` and `\stopclr` to turn-off the coloring.

**Code**

```
\documentclass[oneside,11pt]{book}

\usepackage[semibold,tt=false]{libertine}
\usepackage{libertinust1math}
\usepackage[font={sf,small},labelsep=quad,labelfont=sc]{caption}
\usepackage[subrefformat=parens]{subcaption}
\usepackage[
  expansion = false ,
  tracking = smallcaps ,
  letterspace = 40 ,
]{microtype}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{acro}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{%
  detect-family, detect-shape,
  product-units = power,
  list-final-separator = {, and },
  retain-explicit-plus,
  input-comparators = {<=>\approx\ge\geq\gg\le\leq\ll\sim\lesssim\gtrsim}
}
\DeclareSIUnit[number-unit-product = ]\percent{\char`\%}


% declare your favorite rgb color specifications here
\def\mycolor{.6 0 .8}
\def\othercolor{1 .2 .5}
\def\somecolor{.5 .8 .3}

\def\stopclr{\pdfliteral{0 g}}
\def\startclr#1{\pdfliteral{#1 rg}}

% color the 'rest' of the row
\def\rowclr#1#2\\{\startclr#1#2\stopclr\\}



\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{ccc}
    %------------------------------------
    \toprule
    A            & B        & C\\
    \midrule
    %------------------------------------
    \rowclr\mycolor
    Bob          & \SI{75}{\percent}    & -1.11\\
    %------------------------------------
    Carla        & \startclr\othercolor \SI{75}{\percent}& 2.22\\
    %------------------------------------
    Dale\stopclr & \SI{75}{\percent}    & -3.33\\
    %------------------------------------
    Ena          & \rowclr\somecolor\SI{75}{\percent}    & 4.44\\
    %------------------------------------
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{A}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi, :-) I would align the minus sign with `siunitx` package and the fullstop.

Comment: @Sebastiano: I know. But the main goal was to manage the colors in the tahle. Therefore, I leave the alignment to the asker.

Comment: I hope you are not offended by my suggestion. My best regards.

Comment: @Sebastiano: I don't see any problem at all. I apologize if any of my statements sounded inappropriate. Anyway, also the minus signs should be improved.

Comment: @MarianG. This helped me so much. Thank you.

Comment: @Andrew: You're welcome!

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
\documentclass[oneside,11pt]{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}

%\usepackage[semibold,tt=false]{libertine}
%\usepackage{libertinust1math}
%\usepackage[font={sf,small},labelsep=quad,labelfont=sc]{caption}
%\usepackage[subrefformat=parens]{subcaption}
%\usepackage[
%  expansion = false ,
%  tracking = smallcaps ,
%  letterspace = 40 ,
%]{microtype}
\usepackage{booktabs}
%\usepackage{acro}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{%
  detect-family, detect-shape,
  product-units = power,
  list-final-separator = {, and },
  retain-explicit-plus,
  input-comparators = {<=>\approx\ge\geq\gg\le\leq\ll\sim\lesssim\gtrsim}
}
\DeclareSIUnit[number-unit-product = ]\percent{\char`\%}

% Code from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/26364/15622
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\@rowstyle}{}
\newcommand*{\rowstyle}[1]{% sets the style of the next row
  \gdef\@rowstyle{#1}%
  \@rowstyle\ignorespaces%
}
\newcolumntype{=}{% resets the row style
  >{\gdef\@rowstyle{}}%
}
\newcolumntype{+}{% adds the current row style to the next column
  >{\@rowstyle}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{=l +l +l}
    \toprule
    A & {B} & {C}\\
    \midrule
    \rowstyle{\color{red}}
    Bob & \SI{75}{\percent} & -1.11\\
    Carla & \SI{75}{\percent} & 2.22\\
    Dale & \SI{75}{\percent} & -3.33\\
    Ena & \SI{75}{\percent} & 4.44\\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{A}
\end{table}

\end{document}
t
```

Comment: @Andrew have alook at the revised code -- i have commented out certain packages and get the desired output -- you can uncomment packages as per choice  -- other than `\makeatletter` in the code you were also missing out on the `xcolor` package