# Adjust row font color, font series and background color at the same time

Tags: tables

I managed to insert a row with custom font series and font color.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tabu}{ l | l l l l }
  \rowfont{\leavevmode\color{red}\bfseries}
    A   & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 
    \hline 
    1   & A & B & C & D \\ 
    2   & A & B & C & D \\ 
    3   & A & B & C & D \\ 
    4   & A & B & C & D \\ 
  \end{tabu}
\end{document}
```

[image]

How can I additionally change the background colour of the row e.g. to black? I experimented with `\rowcolor` but it returns an error. Perhaps this can be achieved with tabulx?

Comment: do not use the tabu package. It is broken and unmaintained (see the readme here https://github.com/tabu-issues-for-future-maintainer/tabu). Use colortbl, tabularray or nicematrix.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! Perhaps my question can be answered using tabularx?

Comment: If you want to extensively use colors in your tables, you should probably have a look at the `nicematrix` or `tabularray` packages. If you only need a few cells colord, `colortbl` might already be enough. You might want to look at the other solutions provided here https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/26360/47927 (where your code example probably also originates from).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `tabularray`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\begin{document}
\begin{tblr}
{
colspec  = {*{5}{Q[c,m]}},
hline{2} = {},
vline{2} = {},
row{1}   = {cmd=\bfseries,bg=black,fg=red},
}
A & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
1 & A & B & C & D \\
2 & A & B & C & D \\
3 & A & B & C & D \\
4 & A & B & C & D \\
\end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The result does not change, but `font=\bfseries` is more appropriate than `cmd=\bfseries`.

Comment: `font` just put `\selectfont` after it. If you don't need `\selectfont`, `cmd` is okay.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

With `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{c|cccc}
\RowStyle[rowcolor=black,color=red,bold]{}
A & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
1 & A & B & C & D \\
2 & A & B & C & D \\
3 & A & B & C & D \\
4 & A & B & C & D \\
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: Thank you for your answer!